# WordPress Genisis Featured page widget with an iframe

Tags: php, html, wordpress, iframe

I have a clients website that uses a WordPress Genisis Framework Child Theme.
One of the widgets that are built into the theme is a featured page widget.  It is placed on the front of the page.  The widget gathers 250 characters and displays that on the front page along with the featured image from that page.

The problem is that because the next page only contains an iframe from another website the WordPress widget does not grab the text, so it leaves a nice blank hole on the clients homepage.  The previous developer set it up this way and didn't bother to plug the hole.

Any ideas how I could get the text to display correctly.
I am familiar with most web languages and the WordPress back end so any suggestions would help.

Comment: attempted adding a longdesc tag to the iframe and created a .txt and a .html doc that contained the description I needed, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to place a hidden div on the page where you paste in the text that you want. It wont be dynamic if the integrated page changes but it could be a possible work around.

Comment: That worked, made the text small so the space it takes up is not noticable

Comment: Awesome That's great.